# Get shared contacts for two users from multiple MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my MySQL database.

The first one stores a list of users, and the other, stores a list of contacts for each user.

Users table:

```
+----+----------+--------------+
| id |   name   | phoneNumber  |
+----+----------+--------------+
|  1 | David    | 661-618-5436 |
|  2 | Sarah    | 818-526-4830 |
|  3 | Suzan    | 323-623-3493 |
+----+----------+--------------+
```

Contacts table:

```
+----+-----------------+--------+--------------+
| id | belongsToUserId |  name  | phoneNumber  |
+----+-----------------+--------+--------------+
|  1 |               1 | Gerard | +18185329384 |
|  2 |               1 | Austin | +18739283847 |
|  3 |               2 | Jamie  | +15655468907 |
|  4 |               2 | Jade   | +19893828192 |
|  5 |               3 | Phil   | +18786754234 |
|  6 |               3 | Duke   | +18765467832 |
|  7 |               3 | Gerard | +18185329384 |
|  8 |               3 | Jade   | +19893828192 |
+----+-----------------+--------+--------------+
```

What I want to do, is create a query that efficiently takes 2 user IDs and returns the common contacts by `phoneNumber` for these two users.

**For example:** User IDs `1` & `3` both have `Gerard | +18185329384` in their contacts so the query will return only him.

What could be the most efficient query for this kind of task?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I think this might be what you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
    c1.id, 
    c1.belongsToUserId, 
    c1.phoneNumber, 
    c1.name 
FROM 
    Contacts c1
JOIN 
    Contacts c2 ON (c1.phoneNumber=c2.phoneNumber AND c2.userId=3)
WHERE 
    c1.belongsToUserId =1
```

Comment: Works like a charm and very tidy. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You want a self-join:

```
select c1.name, c1.phonenumber
from contacts c1 join
     contacts c2
     on c1.name = c2.name and c1.phonenumber = c2.phonenumber and
        c1.belongsToUserId = 1 and
        c2.belongsToUserId = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following SELECT will give you all contacts who has more than 1 User.

```
  SELECT Contacts.name, Contacts.phoneNumber
    FROM Users INNER JOIN Contacts ON (Users.id = Contacts.belongsToUserId)
GROUP BY Contacts.name, Contacts.phoneNumber
  HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query will display shared contact along with the `UseID` who's having common contacts.

If you just want to show details of shared contacts, then you can skip first 2 columns.

```
select min(belongsToUserId) as User1,
       max(belongsToUserId) as User2,
       name,
       phone Number
from contacts
group by name,phoneNumber
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    cp.name, 
    cs.phoneNumber 
FROM 
    Contacts cp 
INNER JOIN Contacts cs ON 
    cp.name = cs.name AND cp.phoneNumber = cs.phoneNumber 
AND
    cp.belongsToUserId IN ( 1,3 );
```